# Software to find duplicate folders (by name) and consolidate their contents

Tags: windows

I need to find a piece of software that searches the folders of my hard drive and when it finds a duplicate FOLDER NAME then it will merge (or suggest to merge) it with a previously found folder of the same name.

Does anyone know of something out there that can do the job?

[Something freeware or portable would be great but not essential]

p.s. For Windows please: XP/Vista/7 etc.

Answer (score 0):

for that purpose I alwasy have an USB stick with me where LiberKey is installed at.
LiberKey contains all kind of apps and tools helpful for visits at friends and parents.
On there is very good duplicate finder.

Comment: Cheers, can you tell me which application in Liberkey does this?

Comment: I need this to find duplicate folder names not the files as such.

Comment: LiberKey uses dupkiller

Comment: solved? choose this answer!